# setCookie from 'cookies-next' didn't work

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js, query-string, setcookie

i want to setCookie named token from token in url query param, but setCookie here not working

```
import { setCookie } from "cookies-next";
import { ParsedUrlQuery } from "querystring";

function CallbackPage() {
  return null;
}

export async function getServerSideProps({
  query,
  res,
}: {
  query: ParsedUrlQuery;
  res: any;
}) {
  const { token } = query;
  if (!token) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        source: ",",
        destination: "https://youtube.com", //example
        permanent: false,
        basePath: false,
      },
    };
  } else {
    setCookie("token", token as string);
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }
}

export default CallbackPage;
```

i've tried `try {setCookie} catch(error) {console.log(error)}` but nothing error message i see, i expected if in url query contain token then set that token to cookie